# $(∪α Aα) × (∪β Bβ) = ∪(α,β) (Aα × Bβ)$

Tags: proof-verification

I am solving the following equation out of a book

$⟦ A^{'}α{'}: α⊂A⟧$ and $⟦ B{'}β{'}: `β{'}⊂B⟧ $

(By the way, what does this notation mean? for any given alpha or beta follows that the given alpha or beta is part of the subset?)

$(∪{'}α{'} A{'}α{'})  × (∪{'}β{'} B{'}β{'}) = ∪(α,β) (A{'}α{'} × B{'}β{'})$

I understand why this is a correct equation. I am having however a hard time writing a correct logical proof. Here is my try.

$⊂$

let $(x,y) ∈ (∪α Aα)  × (∪{'}β{'} B{'}β{'})$

$⇔ x∈ (∪α Aα) ^  y∈  (∪{'}β{'} B{'}β{'})$

$⇔ ∃α: x∈Aα ^ ∃β: y∈B{'}β{'}$

Let αo and βo be such indexes

$⇒ (x,y) ∈  ∪(α,β) (Aα × B{'}β{'})$ for  $α{'}o{'}$ and $β{'}o{'}$

---

$⊃$

let $(x,y) ∈   ∪(α,β) (Aα × B{'}β{'})$

$⇔ ∃α∃{'}β{'}: (x,y) ∈ (Aα × B{'}β{'})$

$⇔ ∃α∃{'}β{'}: x∈ Aα ^  y∈B{'}β{'}$

(i was wondering if i could use this rule here? where as px and qx are attributes)

$∃x: p(x)^ q(x) ⇒ ∃x:p(x) ^ ∃x:q(x)$

Let αo and βo be such indexes

$⇒ (x,y) ∈  (∪α Aα)  × (∪{'}β{'} B{'}β{'})$ for  αo and βo

Is the proof correct ? Is there a better one?

Also how can I subscript and superscript when writing a question? 
Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me (aside from the formatting)

Comment: Oh ok so my proof is correct? Nice
(i was wondering if i could use this rule here? where as px and qx are attributes)
∃x: p(x)^ q(x) ⇒ ∃x:p(x) ^ ∃x:q(x)

Comment: @shaun I am using Analysis I by Herbert Amann. There is an English translation as far as I know.